# WriteToText works in DirectRunner but fails with TypeError in DataflowRunner

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I can run this code with `DirectRunner` and it works fine. With `DataflowRunner` it crashes with:

> TypeError: process() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given) [while
>   running 'write_text/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']`

My apache-beam-sdk is cloned and built from master as directed in the instructions. It builds as `apache-beam-sdk==0.6.0.dev0`. I'm suspicious of the version however since (I think) I saw the code change without the version changing recently (`NewDoFn` disappeared but the version didn't change).

I'm not sure if it's the source of the problem, but it seems like there is a mismatch in the installed sdk and the dataflow containers. I get another mismatch-type error where `DirectRunner` passes `element` directly to my `DoFn.process()` while `DataflowRunner` passes `context`.

I tried to isolate this to the simplest code possible:

```
import uuid
import apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options
import apache_beam as beam

runner = 'DataflowRunner'
# runner = 'DirectRunner'

options = beam.utils.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
gcloud_options = options.view_as(beam.utils.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions)
gcloud_options.job_name = 'a' + str(uuid.uuid4())
gcloud_options.project = 'your-project'
gcloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://your-bucket/beam/staging'
gcloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://your-bucket/beam/temp'
options.view_as(beam.utils.pipeline_options.StandardOptions).runner = runner

p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
(p
 | 'some_strings' >> beam.Create(tuple('asdfqwert'))
 | 'write_text' >> beam.io.WriteToText('strings', file_name_suffix='.txt')
 )
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Full output:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
/Users/john/miniconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:136: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Any.
  warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
DEPRECATION: pip install --download has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now has a download command that should be used instead.
Collecting google-cloud-dataflow==0.5.1
  Using cached google-cloud-dataflow-0.5.1.tar.gz
  Saved /var/folders/v3/61xx4nnn6p36n5m9fp4qdwtr0000gn/T/tmpuCWoeh/google-cloud-dataflow-0.5.1.tar.gz
Successfully downloaded google-cloud-dataflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reproduce_bug.py", line 28, in <module>
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/Users/john/miniconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow_runner.py", line 706, in wait_until_finish
    (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
(70278eb56b40fd94): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 514, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 899, in dataflow_worker.executor.MapTaskExecutor.execute (dataflow_worker/executor.c:26452)
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 191, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:7575)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 196, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:7480)
    with self.spec.source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 206, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:7425)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 136, in dataflow_worker.executor.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/executor.c:5749)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 83, in dataflow_worker.executor.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/executor.c:3884)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 505, in dataflow_worker.executor.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:15525)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 163, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:4862)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 270, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7749)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8108)
    raise type(exn), args, sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 268, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7660)
    self.old_dofn_process(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 173, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.old_dofn_process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5182)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(self.context))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 152, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.__init__.lambda3 (apache_beam/runners/common.c:3640)
    self.dofn_process = lambda context: fn.process(context, *args)
TypeError: process() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given) [while running 'write_text/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your environment has version 0.5.1 installed (see the top of your stack trace), but you are building with the HEAD of the python repo.

You can create a new `virtualenv` environment that has the right version of the SDK.

- If you want to run against Python HEAD, then you need to set the `sdk_location` flag when running your pipeline.
- If you want to run against a released version, install the SDK using `pip install google-cloud-dataflow`, and run your pipeline normally. (Preferrably in a virtual environment using `virtualenv`)

As a note, it's probably best if you use a released version.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder where/if I went wrong on the setup to get the difference. I will try it out today.

Comment: You should be fine doing `virtualenv venv ; source venv/bin/activate ; pip install apache_beam`

Comment: I don't see a package called `apache_beam` or anything similar on pypi. Did I miss it? `pip install google-cloud-dataflow` results in `google-cloud-dataflow-0.5.5` which according to your description suggests that it is using beam 0.5.5 which will not match the default pipeline version. The install instructions on the apache beam repository itself say to clone the repo which will result in HEAD. Am I missing something or are the documentation+repo+pypi all out of sync with versioning? P.S. conda 4 life!

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right, you should install the `google-cloud-dataflow` package with pip, and then run your pipeline afterwards. If you're installing it on your own system, you may want to uninstall it first to have a clean install.

Comment: Ok that worked. If you could upate your answer with the final solution from these comments, I'll mark it as solved. You might want to add a note in the repo that the usual way is to install from pypi instead of from a clone and also that if you clone you have to specify the version. Thanks for your help Pablo.

Comment: Done. No problem!